# Dynamic Variable Content JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<script>   
function zeigeBildGross1(Bild1){
    document.getElementById("Bild1").width = 500;
    document.getElementById("Bild1").height = 300;
}
   
function zeigeBildGross2(Bild2){
 document.getElementById("Bild1").width = 500;
 document.getElementById("Bild1").height = 300;
}
   
function zeigeBildGross3(Bild3){
 document.getElementById("Bild1").width = 500;
 document.getElementById("Bild1").height = 300;
}
   
function zeigeBildGross4(Bild4){
 document.getElementById("Bild1").width = 500;
 document.getElementById("Bild1").height = 300;
}
</script>
<noscript>
Bitte JavaScript in Ihrem Browser aktivieren!
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
 <img id="Bild1" width=300 height=200 onclick=zeigeBildGross(Bild1) src="http://getafteritsales.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Brett-Zalaski-1.png" >
 <img id="Bild2" width=300 height=200 onclick=zeigeBildGross(Bild2) src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Number_2_in_light_blue_rounded_square.svg/1024px-Number_2_in_light_blue_rounded_square.svg.png"><br>
 <img id="Bild3" width=300 height=200 onclick=zeigeBildGross(Bild3) src="https://p3cdn2static.sharpschool.com/common/resources/images/Cliparts/Math/Number%203%20Violet.png">
 <img id="Bild4" width=300 height=200 onclick=zeigeBildGross(Bild4) src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/m/e/u/E/z/k/yellow-rounded-number-4-md.png"><br>
</body>
```

Hello,
I want to code a website using HTML and JS, where 4 pictures are shown.
If I press on one picture, it should be resized.

Is it possible, to get a "dynamic" variable?

My idea was, to get a new variable which can have the content Bild1, Bild2, Bild3 or Bild4, depending on which picture was pressed before so there's not the same function for each case just with a different word.

For example:

```
function zeigeBildGross(){
    var x = <!-- depending on which pic was pressed either: Bild1, Bild2, Bild3 or Bild4 !-->
    document.getElementById(x).width = 500;
    document.getElementById(x).height = 300;
}
```

Is that possible?

Thank you for reading,
Stöger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply deliver the id of your image to the function:

HTML:
    `<img src="Bild1.jpg" id="Bild1" width="300" height="200" onclick="zeigeBildGross(this.id)">`

Javascript:

```
function zeigeBildGross(id){
    document.getElementById(id).width = 500;
    document.getElementById(id).height = 300;
}
```

Cleaner version:

`<img src="Bild1.jpg" id="Bild1" width="300" height="200" onclick="zeigeBildGross(this)">`

Javascript:

```
function zeigeBildGross(bild){
    bild.width = 500;
    bild.height = 300;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's all working now.
But I wasn't able to put only _this_ into the brackets, it works with **this.id** only!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a variable that contains the image being clicked, it already exists as the context in the `onclick` event handler.

Simply pass `this` as parameter to the function, and you can use that to access the element:

```js
function zeigeBildGross(bild){
    bild.width = 500;
    bild.height = 300;
}
```

```html
<img id="Bild1" width=300 height=200 onclick="zeigeBildGross(this)" src="http://getafteritsales.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Brett-Zalaski-1.png" >
<img id="Bild2" width=300 height=200 onclick="zeigeBildGross(this)" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Number_2_in_light_blue_rounded_square.svg/1024px-Number_2_in_light_blue_rounded_square.svg.png"><br>
<img id="Bild3" width=300 height=200 onclick="zeigeBildGross(this)" src="https://p3cdn2static.sharpschool.com/common/resources/images/Cliparts/Math/Number%203%20Violet.png">
<img id="Bild4" width=300 height=200 onclick="zeigeBildGross(this)" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/m/e/u/E/z/k/yellow-rounded-number-4-md.png"><br>
```

Comment: How I already mentioned in my comment on @Tyr's answer, it's not working with this (in my case). I have to put _this.id_

Comment: @Stöger: If you pass `this.id` to the function then you get the id of the element, and you have to use `getElementById` to get a reference to the element that you already had a reference to. If you pass `this` to the function you have the reference to the element and you don't need to find the element again, just use the parameter to access the element. See the code in my example. Also, if you pass the element reference instead of the id, the elements doesn't need an id for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Now I understand why I wasn't able to use _this_, thanks!